# How to force status bar update?

Tags: tmux

With `set -wg automatic-rename on` and `set -wg automatic-rename-format "#{pane_title}"`, when I change the title of a pane with `select-pane -T` the status bar does not update until the expiration of the `status-interval` so there is often a noticeable latency of several seconds before the text in the status bar is updated. Is there a command to force an update? (It seems that `refresh-client -S` ought to work....but it does not. )

(Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58138421/how-to-force-status-bar-update, which is too old to migrate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean "change the title of a pane with select-pane"? Do you mean change the active pane? I assume it is the window name in the window list that you expect to change?

I don't see any problem with this, switching pane should immediately redraw the status line, it doesn't depend on status-interval.

What tmux version are you using and what do you have in automatic-rename-format?

If the program in the pane changes it can take a few seconds because automatic-rename-format uses pane_current_command which is only refreshed when the pane is active (that is, when there is output).

Comment: I mean `select-pane -T "new-title"`.  This does not change the active pane, it just changes the title of the current pane.  But the status line will not redraw until status-interval expires.

Comment: tmux version is `next-3.1`, built from  e6b02dec199a0f058aee4e9575f57d92b39501f5 (I think)

Comment: `set -wg automatic-rename-format "#{pane_title}"`

Comment: Just rebuilt with `tmux 3.0a-211-g61b075a2`, same behavior.

Comment: automatic-rename is expensive so happens at most every 500 ms and only when the pane has changed (has output). It's separate and not triggered by select-pane -T or by status line redraw (although it'll trigger a redraw). So it will change at most 500 ms after the pane generates some output. You could turn automatic-rename off and on again, that will force it to be applied. Or if you just want the status line to change immediately, why not put pane_title in window-status-format and window-status-current-format instead of window_name? selectp -T always triggers a status line update.

Comment: If you still want to be able to rename windows manually, you could check automatic-rename (tmux will turn it off when the window is renamed manually), so something like `#{?automatic-rename,#{pane_title},#{window_name}}` in window-status-format and window-status-current-format.

Comment: Looks like putting pane_title in window-satus-format is what I'm after.  Thanks!